# MATLAB: How to use index-number in a vector filter

Tags: matlab, syntax, vector

I have a vector filter and I need to use the vector element index-number within the filter.
What would the syntax be for the `INDEXNUMBER` in the below example?

```
myVector(myVector < 0.05*(INDEXNUMBER/(120-INDEXNUMBER)));
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, you would just substitute `myVector` for `INDEXNUMBER`:

```
myVector  = rand(1,10);
selection = myVector(myVector < 0.05*(myVector/(120-myVector)));
```

The logical indexing (the part inside the outermost parenthesis, second line) is simply doing a logical comparison on all elements of myVector, returning an equal length vector of `0`'s and `1`'s, and the selecting the elements of `myVector` which correspond to the `1`'s. If this isn't what you're doing, just make sure that your dimensions work out correctly (size of left hand inequality == size of right hand inequality == size of variable being selected) and all should be well.

---

To use the position of each number, you could use the following:

```
myVector  = rand(1,10);
indices   = 1:length(myVector);
selection = myVector(myVector < 0.05*(indices/(120-indices)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I substitue myVector for INDEXNUMBER will the values of myVector be used or the position of the element(index number)?

Comment: Answer amended to address your comment.